# Hide the mouse cursor in Opera 10 Kiosk Mode

Tags: html, opera, kiosk

Seems I can't use cursor:url(); with opera and from what I can tell they removed the hide cursor setting from opera.ini.

We're running an app in kiosk mode on a touch PC and would like to hide the mouse cursor. any idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Try loading a 1x1 transparent image instead of empty url?

Answer (score 0):

I'm running a beta version of Opera 11 for a kiosk, and I was able to go to opera:config, search for 'cursor' and check a box to hide the cursor.

Answer (score 0):

I [found](http://help.lockergnome.com/office/Hide-mouse-pointer-Kiosk-mode--ftopict462706.html) a preliminary solution: Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>H</kbd> (<kbd>Option</kbd>-<kbd>H</kbd> on Mac) in Fullscreen Mode. Works fine for me in Opera 11.11. But you have to trigger it manually.

In opera:config, there's no option for disabling the cursor, unfortunately.

Maybe you can experiment with Chromeless, by the way.