# HTML/CSS: get rid of cursor in opera

Tags: html, css, opera

building a website for a touch PC and need to know how to make the cursor disappear completely in opera.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following CSS rule:

```
cursor: none;
```

That's <strike>likeliest</strike> *unlikely* to be supported, as it was introduced in CSS3, and has not yet reached wide adoption.

If that's not supported in Opera, you could try:

```
cursor: url('/path/to/empty/image.format');
```

<strike>That should set the cursor to appear as that image, which could be a blank/transparent 1x1 image.</strike>

---

EDIT: It looks like neither of these options is supported yet in Opera (though both are [valid CSS3.](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-ui/#cursor)) . Pending another idea, my above examples won't work in Opera.

Quirks Mode has an excellent grid where you can test out the support for each property: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/cursor.html Just mouseover each column name to see how it renders in Opera.

Comment: both of these dont seem to work in opera. Are they supported?

Comment: cursor: none is invalid css.  The other notation is not supported by Opera: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3606010/hide-the-mouse-cursor-in-opera-10-kiosk-mode

Comment: `cursor: none;` is not invalid CSS. It was introduced in the CSS3 spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-ui/#cursor
 , but it seems you're right that its not supported in Opera.

Comment: Not with CSS, no. There could be a JavaScript solution, though.